# ROS & OpenCV (python): Coding help for depth map using 2 cameras

Tags: opencv, ros

So I'm trying to build a depth map using two stereo images , from two cameras on my baxter robot. The structure of my code looks very similar to this one here: http://wiki.ros.org/cv_bridge/Tutorials/ConvertingBetweenROSImagesAndOpenCVImagesPython
(the code under "01 An example ROS node")

My code is exactly like that one, minus all the rows columns and channels operations (basically my code is just taking a picture from my robot's camera, converting it to an opencv2 type and then displaying it)

What i want to be able to do, is to subscribe to a second camera, and using this piece of code (http://docs.opencv.org/master/dd/d53/tutorial_py_depthmap.html#gsc.tab=0) be able to create a depth map.

My problem is, with the main code structure that i have, i don't know how to subscribe to a second camera (do i need a second callback function?) and how/where would i add in the piece of code for the depth map operation?

Comment: The stereo images need to be time-synchronized to be able to compute a depth map, so that gives a hint on what you might want to do. Take a look at ROS message filters, in particular the [TimeSynchronizer](http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters#Time_Synchronizer). You may also want to study the source code for [stereo_image_proc](http://wiki.ros.org/stereo_image_proc) to study how others have handled this problem conceptually (click on e.g. the link "indigo" to get the wiki visible; it seems to not be up to date for kinetic).